# Struggling to understand the result of the "Outer" applied on two arrays via the subtraction being used as the vectorized FUN

Tags: r

I'm trying to undrestand the **outer** in R. Here is my test case:

```
myarray <- array(data = c(0,5,7,3), dim = c(2,2))
myarray
outer_op <- outer(myarray, myarray, "-")
outer_op
```

Based on what I've understood (or I'd rather say misunderstood) so far, each element in the array will be associated via FUN, a vectorized function, which in my test case is the subtraction operator, with all other elements in the array, therefore each time a pair of values. So the following is what I would excpect R to print if I had to do the outer operation by hand on a piece of paper:

```
, , 1, 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0   -7
[2,]   -5   -3

, , 2, 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   -5    2
[2,]    0   -2

, , 1, 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   -7    0
[2,]   -2   -4

, , 2, 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   -3    4
[2,]    2    0
```

What I've done, is that I took each element at the position 
(i,j) = (row, column) and I've subtracted each time from one of other elements in the matrix.
So for example for the first matrix (, , 1, 1) here is what I've done:

```
0 - 0 = 0       = new element at the first row and first column after outer.
0 - 5 = -5      = new element at the second row and first column after outer.
0 - 7 = -7      = new element at the first row and second column after outer.
0 - 3 = -3      = new element at the second row and second column after outer.
```

But it seems that I don't understand the concept as the result provided by 
R is compltey different:

```
, , 1, 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    7
[2,]    5    3

, , 2, 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   -5    2
[2,]    0   -2

, , 1, 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   -7    0
[2,]   -2   -4

, , 2, 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   -3    4
[2,]    2    0
```

So I don't really get how R has done the subtraction between elements to 
provide theses matrixes. I'd appreciate if you could kindly make some 
clarifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start with `myarray` and subtract `myarray[1,1]` you get

```
myarray - myarray[1, 1]
#>      [,1] [,2]
#> [1,]    0    7
#> [2,]    5    3
```

Then if you take `myarray` and subtract `myarray[2, 1]` you get

```
myarray - myarray[2, 1]
#>      [,1] [,2]
#> [1,]   -5    2
#> [2,]    0   -2
```

And so on.

So basically the order of subtraction is just reversed from how you have done it by hand. It starts with `myarray` and subtracts a single number (taken from the second copy of `myarray`) from the whole of the first array to give each resultant slice.

You can see this more clearly if you use an array full of zeros and exchange the order:

```r
zeroarray <- array(data = c(0, 0, 0, 0), dim = c(2, 2))
outer(myarray, zeroarray, "-")
#> , , 1, 1
#> 
#>      [,1] [,2]
#> [1,]    0    7
#> [2,]    5    3
#> 
#> , , 2, 1
#> 
#>      [,1] [,2]
#> [1,]    0    7
#> [2,]    5    3
#> 
#> , , 1, 2
#> 
#>      [,1] [,2]
#> [1,]    0    7
#> [2,]    5    3
#> 
#> , , 2, 2
#> 
#>      [,1] [,2]
#> [1,]    0    7
#> [2,]    5    3
```

Now reverse the order and each element of `myarray` is taken away from the zero array:

```
outer(zeroarray, myarray, "-")
#> , , 1, 1
#> 
#>      [,1] [,2]
#> [1,]    0    0
#> [2,]    0    0
#> 
#> , , 2, 1
#> 
#>      [,1] [,2]
#> [1,]   -5   -5
#> [2,]   -5   -5
#> 
#> , , 1, 2
#> 
#>      [,1] [,2]
#> [1,]   -7   -7
#> [2,]   -7   -7
#> 
#> , , 2, 2
#> 
#>      [,1] [,2]
#> [1,]   -3   -3
#> [2,]   -3   -3
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and this clear and brilliant explanation! Indeed, what I hadn't understood was the fact the each time one element was being selected from the 2nd array to be associated with all elements of the 1st one via the FUN. I don't know why I thought that I had to start from the first array, and therefore always start from the left side, maybe I'd misunderstood the documentation: "The outer product of the arrays 'X' and 'Y' is the array ‘A’ with dimension 'c(dim(X), dim(Y))' where element 'A[c(**arrayindex.x**, arrayindex.y)] = FUN(X[**arrayindex.x**], Y[arrayindex.y], ...)'"